# Cannot replace nested list value to X due to TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list error

Tags: python, list, typeerror, nested-lists, index-error

I am trying to do an exercise learning Python for nested lists and I the way it works is that you have a grid, and then based on what you enter, it will replace that position with an "X". You also need to do it while entering a 2 digit number. I was able to get to a point where the input was turned into a list and was able to make sure they were integers too.

```
#  Don't change the code below 
row1 = ["⬜️","️⬜️","️⬜️"]
row2 = ["⬜️","⬜️","️⬜️"]
row3 = ["⬜️️","⬜️️","⬜️️"]
map = [row1, row2, row3]
print(f"{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}")
position = input("Where do you want to put the treasure? ")
#  Don't change the code above 

#Write your code below this row 


#Take the 2-digit number and split into the column and row numbers
#Also now integers to find the indexes
column_num = int(position[0])
row_num = int(position[1])

#Take the 2 numbers, and use to make where to mark the X
new_list = [column_num, row_num]
new_column = new_list[0]
new_row = new_list[1]
x = [new_column] + [new_row]
print(new_list)
print(x)

# Replace the new_list list, which have the indexes, into X
map[new_list] = "X"

#Write your code above this row 

#  Don't change the code below 
print(f"{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}")
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*******\IdeaProjects\_100DaysOfCodev2\.idea\Day 4 - Beginner - Randomisation and Python Lists\6- [Exercise] - Treasure Map.py", line 27, in <module>
    map[new_list] = "X"
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

I have tried to change the list into an "int" but then it tells me not tuple instead of list.

Anyone got any ideas? I want to understand what I am missing here, instead of going back and playing the solution.

I tried to separate the values of the new list so they would be integers but I needed them to be a set of index but it won't work because it becomes a list again. I have tried summoning different things from "map" nested list and I get index errors that it is out of index range as well. Also we are not in "for, in" yet or defining functions yet. Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\e792977\IdeaProjects_100DaysOfCodev2.idea\Day 4 - Beginner - Randomisation and Python Lists\6- [Exercise] - Treasure Map.py", line 27, in 
map[new_list] = "X"
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Comment: Look at the error closely ```TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list```, your variable ```new_list``` is a list (duh) and you can index your other list ```map``` using another list.

Comment: Also you've overridden the built-in function ```map``` with a variable also named ```map```. Rename your variable if you're trying to use the function

Comment: Given the notes in the code I believe that is the fault of the problem not the student.

Comment: Think carefully about the logic of the code. If I write `x = [1, 1]` and then `map[x]`, should that be valid? What should be the result? Why do you think so? (Hint: **what are the elements of `map`**? What **indices** do they have?) (Hint: Notice how it is perfectly allowed to write something like `[1, 2, [3, 4], 5]` and work with that? Does this tell you something about how nested lists work in Python?)

Comment: (I'm sure there is a better duplicate for this, but it is the one I could find. This question is very common.)

Comment: Note that python lists are `0-indexed` and you will want to make sure your input aligns with that or alternatively if you user expects to use `1-based indexing` that your use of their input accounts for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify the 2 indices explicitly:

```py
    map[new_list[0]][new_list[1]] = "X"
```

or in the context of your current solution something like:

```py
#  Don't change the code below 
row1 = ["⬜️","️⬜️","️⬜️"]
row2 = ["⬜️","⬜️","️⬜️"]
row3 = ["⬜️️","⬜️️","⬜️️"]
map = [row1, row2, row3]
print(f"{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}")
position = input("Where do you want to put the treasure? ")
#  Don't change the code above 

#Write your code below this row 
x_index = int(position[0]) - 1      ## assume that users will use 1 indexing
y_index = int(position[1]) - 1
map[y_index][x_index] = "X"
#Write your code above this row 

#  Don't change the code below 
print(f"{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}")
```

**Note:**

As others have pointed out, `map` is a poor choice for a variable name as it will hide the python function `map()`. You can find a full list of such here : [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

Secondly, python lists are `0-indexed` and if our user is not expecting that there might be confusion. This code takes their requested row and column and converts it to `0-indexed` assuming that they expected `row 1` to be the "first" row.

Finally, I expect that when asked for coordinates that I give them in the following order (`xy`):

- x (the row offset)
- y (the column offset)

However, each "row" of data is the `i-th y-offset` and each cell of data in a given row is the `j-th x-offset` so when we go to set our "X" we will index into our data via `map[y_index][x_index]` and not `map[x_index][y_index]` as one might intuit.

Comment: mind if I elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: @JonSG: Knock yourself out.

Comment: Feel free to revert if you don't feel this adds value or was in the spirit of your original post. I'll not mind.

Comment: When I do this, it gives me this error -     

x = map[new_list[0][new_list[1]]]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

I changed the ints from the top and created a new variable where it converted the list into an 'int'. And it gives me his error:

    new_list_int = int(new_list)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

I'm stuck in a loop. I change it to 'int' it can't be 'int' I don't change it, it can't be a list.

Comment: No go. It has one more bracket than needed. Also putting everything in another set of brackets puts everything out of index range with an IndexError.

Comment: Issue solved. I followed @ScottHunter what you said about combining the map and formatting it with the list index and equaling to X. Thank you very much!